# PDF.js getTextContent returning text in wrong order

Tags: javascript, excel, pdf, promise, pdf.js

I'm having a problem extracting text from a pdf using PDF.js.  I'm using a PDF that was exported from Excel, and thus has multiple rows/columns.  Here's the function I'm using to get the text:

```
 gettext: function(url, name){
     var self = this;
     var data = url;
     console.log('attempting to get text');
     return pdfjs.getDocument(data).then(function(pdf) {
     var pages = [];
     for (var i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
         pages.push(i);
     }
     return Promise.all(pages.map(function(pageNumber) {
         return pdf.getPage(pageNumber + 1).then(function(page) {
         return page.getTextContent().then(function(textContent) {
             return textContent.items.map(function(item) {

             return item.str;
             }).join('###');
         });
         });
     })).then(function(pages) {
         return pages.join("\r\n")
     });
     }).then(function(pages){
     return self.parsetext(pages, url, name);        
     });        
 },
```

This works very well for most of the text contents.  The very annoying issue is that, for a certain section, the contents are mixed up.  The following is being logged by the `gettext` function when it reaches the *beschreibung* section:

One odd thing happening here: the *beschreibung* section is being extracted at the end of the text, even though it is just another column like *kks* or *seite*.  I can work with this if it retains the correct order, but as you can see below, it doesn't.

```
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: 12
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: MA-KF12
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: 26
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: MA-KF12
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: 33
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: MA-KF12
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: 44
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: MA-KF12
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: 82
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: Inbetriebnahme
2Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: Anhang
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: Vorwort
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: Produktübersicht
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: Grundlagen der Kommunikation
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: Montage und Verdrahtung
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: Vorwort
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: Produktübersicht
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: Grundlagen der Kommunikation
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: Montage und Verdrahtung
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: Inbetriebnahme
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: Produktübersicht
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: Grundlagen der Kommunikation
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: Montage und Verdrahtung
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: Inbetriebnahme
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: Anhang
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: Produktdaten
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: Dokumentation
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: Beschreibung
Data.vue?1e15:250 item string: Vorwort
```

As you can see, the order is off (but only slightly...)

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

[image]

Comment: `As you can see, the order is off (but only slightly...)` - it's not clear

Comment: @JaromandaX  If you take `Inbetriebnahme` and `Anhang` (the first entries returned) and shift them down a few cells, the order will be correct.  So it's not random, but it's also getting screwed up somehow.

Comment: can you confirm that `textContent.items` is in the order you expect

Comment: @JaromandaX  No it's not -- I think that's the source of the problem.  The order I expect is in the PDF screenshot, and what is logged to the screen is the string properties (in order) from textContent.items

Comment: getTextContent returns text content in order how glyphs are printed; and per spec, a text extraction performance "is significantly better if the text strings are as long as possible and are shown in natural reading order". No PDF attached, so it's hard to tell how strings are shown in the PDF.

Comment: @async5  The screenshot shows how the strings are in the PDF, but if having the original might help, what's a good way for me to attach it?

Comment: publish entire example e.g. at github pages?

Comment: To see what PDF has inside use http://brendandahl.github.io/pdf.js.utils/browser/ -- see Root->Pages->..->Contents-><view contents>

Comment: @async5   There isn't a <view contents> item under contents -- it's either count, kids, or type.  There is a view contents under metadata, though.  I have an example of a similar pdf that does work as expected and doesn't garble the order, and I'm comparing its metadata with that of the problematic one to see if I can spot anything...

Comment: @async5  I can work on getting these on gh pages if you're willing to take a look.

Comment: @async5  I noticed that when I do copy+paste with the pdf, the text that I get out of it is already out of order, before I try anything in pdf.js.  Does this mean that the pdf is just problematic and must be prepared differently?