# pdf.js mozilla lib issue get or extract pure text with right order

Tags: javascript, pdf, extract, pdf.js

I need get pure text from pdf using pdf.js with right order of text.
I need help with Mozilla's pdf.js 2.x (I use 2.0.550).
I send some days to find solution without any success.

Goal: extract correct pure text from pdf file with Mozilla's pdf.js without rendering of pdf image (canvas or svg) and better without text layer if it is possible.

*I know here is the similar question but without answer - reason and how fix it. Link is [PDF.js getTextContent returning text in wrong order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44520376/pdf-js-gettextcontent-returning-text-in-wrong-order)
Also I review other questions in the list with possible answers.*

It is ok to get from each page. I use getTextContent() function and it returns an object with arrays of 'items'. There is an object with elements '.str' with the text in page is needed. 
But order is wrong. Is it possible to get right order of text like in original page?

In result you can see that order is wrong.
But I'm surprised a lot because with same or similar code render layer shows correct image. When I inspect pdfjs app with text layer I can see a lot of  tags with different parts of text. Sometimes numbers on one line. I looks each  tag contains font\style text group.

- Is it possible?
- Is there are mistakes in code ? How I can fix it?
- Is there some attribute that shows order I can use to restore original text?
- Maybe other function to extract text?
- Other ideas?

Add-on:
I see obj{}.items[].transform[] array with element [4] like X and element [5] like Y coordinates. Is it true?
Is it useful to manually sort and get right order of text from top to down and from left to right each 'str' element ?
Maybe here is in Pdf.js some function to do it better?

Thanks in advance.

Technical specs:
Link to PDF file to test:
https://www.pdfill.com/example/pdf_commenting_new.pdf
The same problem with other pdf.

Code:

```
let pdfurl = "https://www.pdfill.com/example/pdf_commenting_new.pdf";
pdfjsLib.getDocument( pdfurl )
  .then(function(pdf) {
      pdf.getPage( i )
      .then(function(page){ 
        return page.getTextContent( render_options ) })
      .then(function(textContent){
        console.log( i, "# textContent :", textContent );
        textContent.items.forEach( (el, ind) => console.log( (++ind) + ". " + el.str ) );
      });

    })
```

Result in console:

```
 1. How to align these objects
 2. You can open a PDF or create a blank PDF by PDFill.
 3. Here are the seven types of PDF Commenting created by PDFill
 4. Goto Page 4: Text Box Tool
 5. Goto Page 6: Sticky Note Tool
 6. Goto Page 7: Popup Tool
 7. Goto Page 8: File Attachment Tool
 8. Goto Page 9: Play Video Tool
 9. Goto Page 11: Line or Arrow Tool
 10. Goto Page 12: Rectangle or Oval Tool
 11. Next Page
 12. Next Page
 13. First Page
 14. Previous Page
 15. Next Page
 16. Last Page
 17. Please save into a new PDF to see the effect!
 18. Online Help
 19. PDFill: PDF Commenting or Annotation
 20. Goto Page 13: Polyline, Cloud and Pencil Tool
 21. Goto Page 2: Select Original Texts
 22. Goto Page 5: Highlight Tool
 23. Goto Page 10: Link Tool
 24. Goto Page 3: Stamp Tool
```

Configuration:
- Web browser and its version: chrome Version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Operating system and its version: Linux 4.15.0-22-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 16 12:15:17 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- NG module - pdfjs-dist
- PDF.js version:2.0.550 (also 2.0.489)
- Angular 6 / node 8x / npm 5x / TS

Answer (score 3):

I got it. 
**Shortly - get all text into an array and/or collection  and sort by opposite Y and then X coordinates from Transform array to get right order.**

Description:
It is very nice to understand that the Y axis in PDF file is in an opposite direction. I got it and find addition info about it after some debugging time.

Thus here is simple work to get common right order of text.
 1. Get all elements as is.
 2. Then find in the Items array Transform array.
 3. Get in the array Transform values X (4th) and Y(5th) positions of this element.
 4. I use Lodash.js to group by 2 categories X and Y array I got finally. Care about you need sort first by Y from bigger to lower because Y is inverse in PDF. Then sort by X;

```
_.orderBy(pagetext, ['y','x'], ['desc', 'asc'] )
```

In the code below I suppose you got PDF page object.
Code:

```
// got text elements from getTextContent() to new array with page, x, y, and text
pagetext.push( 
{ 'p': i, 'x': el.transform[4], 'y': el.transform[5], 't': el.str } )
// follow what we got
          console.log( (++ind) + ". " 
          +" t: "+ el.transform
          +" x= "+ el.transform[4]
          +" y= "+ el.transform[5]
          +" | "+ el.str );

        })    

        return pagetext; // return all text as result from page
      })
      .then(function(ptext){
    // be careful :)
    // resort order by opposite Y and then X coordinates
            let pagetext = ptext;
            console.log( "# it is wrong # pagetext = ", pagetext );
        let p2 = _.orderBy(pagetext, ['y','x'], ['desc', 'asc'] )
        console.log( "# it is correct # pagetext = ", p2 );

});
```

Here is an example of array about 1 text element on a page. You will get a lot of elements with getTextContent in custom order as I showed above in the question.

```
//From console:
Object
items : Array(24)
str : "How to align these objects"
transform : (6) [18, 0, 0, 18, 349.76, 335.25]
width : 190.78199999999998
__proto__
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it

```
  //first sort the fragments by Y desc , X asc to order the text
  const sorted = data.items.sort(
    (a, b) => b.transform[5] - a.transform[5] || a.transform[4] - b.transform[4]
  );

  // generate the string chain
  const text = sorted.map((e) => e.str).join();
```